# How to iterate complicated dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, nested, iteration

First of all, I would like to let you know that I didn't find an answer specific to my question in stack overflow. So asking for your kind suggestions. I want to iterate through the below nested dictionary to create a string given below. Can you please advise.

```py
features = {
    "ptf_overall2": {
        "1": {
            "groupBy": {
                "1": {"column": "country"},
                "2": {"column": "measurement_group"},
                "3": {"column": "bpid"},
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "number_of_journeys_customer_eligible": {
                "operation": "countDistinct",
                "column": "journeyinstanceid",
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "number_of_journeys_customer_been_contacted": {
                "operation": "sum",
                "column": "journey_email_been_sent_flag",
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Basically I would need to identify the aggregation operation and order of those columns associated with it and then append the columns in the aggregation operation as given below. Order is so important for me.

```
ptf_overall2.groupBy('country', 'measurement_group', 'bpid').
```

With below iteration, I get the error as below

```
for i in features.get("ptf_overall2"):
    print(features.get("ptf_overall2")[i])
    for j in features.get("ptf_overall2")[i]:
        print(features.get("ptf_overall2")[j])
```

Error

```
KeyError: 'GroupBy'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2704284371067158> in <module>
      2   #print(features.get('ptf_overall2')[i])
      3   for j in features.get('ptf_overall2')[i]:
----> 4     print(features.get('ptf_overall2')[j])

KeyError: 'GroupBy'
```

Comment: I'm not following what the desired output should be, here.

Comment: @AKX this should be the output `ptf_overall2.groupBy('country', 'measurement_group', 'bpid')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this. It should work for any dict that has exactly one top-level key, followed by a dict of dicts, one of which should have a `groupBy` key.

```
features = {
    "ptf_overall2": {
        "1": {
            "groupBy": {
                "1": {"column": "country"},
                "2": {"column": "measurement_group"},
                "3": {"column": "bpid"},
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "number_of_journeys_customer_eligible": {
                "operation": "countDistinct",
                "column": "journeyinstanceid",
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "number_of_journeys_customer_been_contacted": {
                "operation": "sum",
                "column": "journey_email_been_sent_flag",
            }
        },
    }
}


def get_group_by(d):
    assert (
        len(d) == 1
    ), "dictionary has more than 1 top-level key"
    key = next(iter(d))  # find first (only) key
    for value in d[key].values():
        if "groupBy" in value:  # found the `groupBy` item...
            columns = [
                c["column"]
                for index, c in sorted(value["groupBy"].items())
            ]
            return f"{key}.groupBy{tuple(columns)}"


print(get_group_by(features))
```

The output is, as expected,

```
ptf_overall2.groupBy('country', 'measurement_group', 'bpid')
```

Comment: Thanks alot @AKX for the quick answer. However thought of asking Is there a way to avoid hardcoding the "groupBy" from the code, instead  automatically find the key and combine.

Comment: What key would you automatically find? You do want a `groupBy` expression in the end...